# How to pass a nested dictionary as parameter to a method?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to have a method with parameter like

```
public int MyMethod(Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,int>> myDict)
{
 ...
}
```

But writing this, I get message that compilation failed and the following explanation:

> The type or namespace name `Dictionary`2' could not be found.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Do you have `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file?

Comment: No, I didn't have. Thank you! (thanks also for editing the question ...)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you include `using System.Collections.Generic;` at the top of your file. Alternatively, you can use the full namespace inline with your code:

```
public int MyMethod(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,int>> myDict)
{

}
```

(but I guess we can both see from this that the `using` directive is a bit nicer)